# Magento Admin redirects to Homepage

Tags: admin, magento-community

I know this is common problem, I tried many solutions but things did not work.
I tried changing the url for admin from dashboard. Now dashboard redirects me to
store home page. I tried deleting cache files and session files. Also 
set `admin/url/use_custom` to `0`, `admin/url/use_custom_path` to `0` in database.
The login page opens as bare html with no css or js files working. when i login it redirects me to store homepage.
Any help would be great! thanks.

**Update:** Also tried changing the `local.xml`. Now the `/index.php/admin gives` 404 error and the new admin name "backend" (`/index.php/backend`) redirects to homepage.

Comment: Are you doing anything out of the ordinary like running Magento from a subdirectory?

Comment: @JonathanHussey I am running magento in a shared hosting and it has public_html as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it. Had to change the

```
web/secure/base_url       http://domainname.com/
web/unsecure/base_url     http://domainname.com/
```

in database.

Comment: both secure and unsecure http?

Comment: @bart2puck , i was working on a dev server where we did not serve via https. For proper functioning `secure` should be `https://domain.com`

Comment: So **WHAT** Was the values before you changed these 2 urls?? Always be specific !

Comment: @PratikCJoshi, i understand it would have been helpful to many people if i could provide more data, but its been around 11 months and i dont remember much of it. Will make it a point to provide as much data as possible next time.

Comment: @codename_subho , see your Question and answer already has 1600+ views. 1600+ people came here and returned with no answer as you have written 1 line answer. **Please** consider editing your answer, because your 1 line answer is equal to no answer to the question or deleted Question/answer.

Comment: Based upon the comments and my knowledge of magento, I presume that you changed `web/secure/base_url` from 'https' to 'http'.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Magento - Wiki - Set up Magento backend on a separate node](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/set_up_magento_backend_on_a_separate_node)

Edit “app/etc/local.xml” and change

```
<frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
```

This will change the name of the path entity used to get access to the admin panel.

Comment: tried it and updated my question.

Comment: what values do you have in the db for `admin/url/use_custom` and `admin/url/use_custom_path`?. Also what version of magento?

Comment: I have 0 for both

Comment: Trying using a different browser (/delete browser cache)

Comment: I did that. As i mentioned in my question. Login page appears as plain html without any css effect. And on logging in  am redirected to store homepage .

Comment: "I tried deleting cache files and session files" is this for your browser or magento server?

Comment: its for magento server. also tried clearing bowser cache and cookies.

Comment: Also i would add that the css and js file for admin login page shows 403error forbidden.and the url is the custom admin url that i tried setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to phpmyadmin** 
search *core_config_data* 
drop or delete cofigration table

```
Validate REMOTE_ADDR

Validate HTTP_VIA

Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

Cleare the Cache and Sir,please go to admin url.
may be it help you or 100% 
@martvent developer